# export a list of datetimes date as string

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datetime, datetime-format

I want to export a list which contains datimes date part as string but the below error ocuured :
System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

the code is:

```
public List<string> ReadDatesDAL(string d)
{
    var q = db.visits.Include("Doctor")
        .Where(i => i.delstatus == false)
        .Where(i => i.doctor.name == d)
        .Select(i => i.start.ToShortDateString());
    return q.ToList();
}
```

Comment: There's no `ToShortDateString` in SQL and no meaningful translation because the *actual* format depends on the end user's locale settings. You need to load the dates first, *then* format them as strings in the format you want

Comment: You don't need `Include` in this query. `Include` isn't a JOIN, it tells EF to eagerly load related objects along with the root object. You can use `.Where(i => i.doctor.name == d)` without it.

Comment: Entity Framework does not support the ToShortDateString() method which is translated to SQL for execution on the database server. Therefore, you cannot use this method directly in a LINQ query.

Answer (score 1):

The error states that `ToShortString()` *"cannot be translated into a store expression"*. Change the `Select` so that it just returns `i.start`. You can then call `ToList()` to run the query and then call `ToShortString()` afterwards.

```
public List<string> ReadDatesDAL(string d)
{
    var q = db.visits.Include("Doctor")
        .Where(i => i.delstatus == false)
        .Where(i => i.doctor.name == d)
        .Select(i => i.start);

    return q.ToList().Select(i => i.ToShortDateString()).ToList();
}
```

Comment: error egain:Cannot implicitly convert type 'type1' to 'type2'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: @seldakabirnejat what is `type1` and `type2`? This answer fixes the problem you asked about. We can't know what the types of the other fields are and why they cause errors. Post the code you tried and the *full* exception text in the question itself

Comment: That sounds like a different issue. I assume you replaced "type1" and "type2" in the error. not knowing what these types are and where they are used means, it's impossible to help much further. I make/made the assumption that the rest of the code works and answered the question as stated.